# reading facebook status and storing it in mysql

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to read all the status messages of a user. I have used the following code.

```
//gets statusid, message and uid of the user
function get_status_message($access_token){
    // Run fql query
  $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . '/fql?q=SELECT+message+,+status_id+,+uid+FROM+status+WHERE+uid=me()'
    . '&access_token=' . $access_token;
  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
  $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);

  //display results of fql query
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r("query results:");
  print_r($fql_query_obj);
  echo '</pre>';
  return $fql_query_obj;
}
```

It returns the following

```
query results:Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [message] => test3
                    [status_id] => 5.0606879274642E+14
                    [uid] => 1.0000029926744E+14
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [message] => test2
                    [status_id] => 5.060443560822E+14
                    [uid] => 1.0000029926744E+14
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [message] => testing !
                    [status_id] => 5.0304255638238E+14
                    [uid] => 1.0000029926744E+14
                )

        )

)
```

I have to retrieve the status id and put it in mysql db. I tried foreach but I am unable to loop. The code below works

but I need to explicitly give the first index value as $value**[0]**["status_id"]. Can someone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the Facebook call actually retrieved data for you to process then loop through the result and insert to your DB, with something like:

```
if(!empty($fql_query_obj['data'])) {
    foreach($fql_query_obj['data'] as $status) {
        $status_id = $status['status_id'];
        // create SQL insert batch
    }
    // Run the insert batch
}
```